# Batch file to loop through wmic output and start program according to what's NOT running

Tags: for-loop, batch-file

I play a game plagued by crashing problems which are non-local in nature and cannot be fixed on my end. I am attempting to make it easier to deal with. I run multiple instances of the game and when one crashes I have to find out which ones are still running to open the appropriate executable from a path which is not already running. I have cobbled together this code from other stack exchange articles which correctly outputs the running processes and paths but I'm having trouble doing anything with it.

```
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions

set EXE=DiabloImmortal.exe

FOR /F %%x IN ('tasklist /NH /FI "IMAGENAME eq %EXE%"') DO IF %%x == %EXE% goto ProcessFound

goto ProcessNotFound

:ProcessFound
wmic process where "name='%EXE%'" get ProcessID, ExecutablePath

goto END

:ProcessNotFound
echo %EXE% is not running
goto END

:END
echo Finished!

pause
```

this is what the output looks like...

```
ExecutablePath                                                                    ProcessId
C:\Program Files (x86)\Diablo Immortal1\Engine\Binaries\Win64\DiabloImmortal.exe  16464
C:\Program Files (x86)\Diablo Immortal2\Engine\Binaries\Win64\DiabloImmortal.exe  15612
```

I have 4 directories named similarly but numbered 1-4 with the number being the last character of the directory path.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Diablo Immortal1

C:\Program Files (x86)\Diablo Immortal2

C:\Program Files (x86)\Diablo Immortal3

C:\Program Files (x86)\Diablo Immortal4

So what I need it to do is.. with this given output it should notice #3 is not running and launch this program.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Diablo Immortal3\Diablo Immortal Launcher.exe

I do not want it to launch all of the missing instances at once as each instance must be fully logged in before starting another instance. So I will run the batch file multiple times as needed...

I attempted to use a FOR loop but my batch script is rusty at best and I was never very fluent with it to begin with. I feel the most optimum approach is a loop or switch style statement combo'd with regular expressions which are also troublesome for me!

I know as game related this isn't considered super important to most people who view it. I work and have 2 kids as many do and this is my one little vice but lately it's become impossible to enjoy as a result of this. I thank you for your time and any contribution you might add, I very much appreciate it!

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this with a batch script? It smells like something that would be much easier with PowerShell.

Comment: That may be the case but batch is the only thing I have any experience with and feel as though I might be able to get there... many of the source posts I used to get this far were full of people going back and forth between batch and PowerShell for similar issues... I tried a few but got further this way.

Answer (score 0):

**untested**

```
@echo off
set "EXE=DiabloImmortal.exe"
:loop
for %%i in (1,2,3,4) do (
  wmic process where "name='%EXE%'" get  ExecutablePath /format:csv|find "Diablo Immortal%%i" >nul || (
    echo %%i not running - restarting...
    ECHO "C:\Program Files (x86)\Diablo Immortal%%i\Engine\Binaries\Win64\DiabloImmortal.exe"
    REM
  )
)
timeout 2 >nul
goto :loop
```

I disabled the execution of the missed instance by just `ECHO`ing it. Try if it works as intended before removing the capital `ECHO` to enable starting the EXE.

Basically, this checks for each of the 4 instances whether the program is running and starts it if it is missing.

Adapt the `timeout` to your needs (be sure to keep it, though; otherwise, the script will work as fast as it can, putting unnecessary load on your CPU). The minimum value is 1 (one second), but set it as high as possible (maybe checking every 5 minutes (300 seconds) is enough for your needs)

If you need a delay between start of instances (if for some reason more than one is missing), do another `timeout` within the loop (where I put the `REM`).

Comment: This worked perfectly I just had to make a couple mods to suite my needs because I cannot load them all back to back like that for some reason the game is using variables in a way that if you load a second instance before finishing to fully log in the previous instance it will bind the account your logging in on the first instance to the 2nd instance.. that said this is perfect to identify which instance isn't running and open it then exit.. For a bit I was literally tempted to quit the game because of the hassle this problem has created me... Thanks to u, Not now! 

Merry Christmas!

Comment: It's still crashing quite a lot in fact if I hadn't solved at least some of the problem I was planning to quit so this at least allows me to continue enjoying it in hopes of a future patch/fix from the devs but they seem to be more interested in the $$ generating aspects of the game not whether or not its playable lol.. thanks again!